# How to calculate proportions for multiple variables in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have four numbers: 4,  3.6,  1.8,  1.2,

Is there a way to find the weights of each of them, so that when I sum the (numbers * their weights), I'll get to a specific number, for example: 2.

So for the number 2, the results will be:

[image]

2 is the input, and the output is the weights. I know there are several weights that answer the question, but I wonder if I can get the solutions.

Is there a way to calculate it in Excel?

Thanks

Comment: There are many, many potential answers... but Solver should be helpful, though you should add some constraints.

Comment: Do the sum of the weight have to always be ***100%*** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data I put the following Objective function in **I3**:

```
=(F2-1)^2+(F4-2)^2
```

I then ran Solver to try to drive this to zero:

[image]

Minimizing the Objective function compels Solver to simultaneously drive the sum of weights to 100% and the sum of weighted values to 2.